# Función imprimir mayúsculas y minúsculas

Tags: python

Tengo que formar una función que imprima mayúscula en una palabra si es par y dejarla en minúscula si es impar, lo que intenté fué esto:

```
def mayusculas_y_minusculas (*kwargs):  
    for letter in kwargs:
        if len(letter)%2==0:
            letter.upper()
        else:
         len(letter)%2!=0
        letter.lower()

mayusculas_y_minusculas ("hola")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unas cuantas cosas:

- La función no imprime nada ni retorna nada, bueno `None` que es lo que toda función retorna por defecto. Por lo tanto, nunca vas a ver resultado alguno.
- La línea `len(letter)%2!=0` en el `else` sobra, aparte de no hacer nada por no estar asociada a ningún condicional o variable, si el `if` no se cumple la palabra es "impar", no hay que comprobar nada.
- No uses `*kwargs`, por convención `kwargs` se usa para que la función acepte un número indeterminado de argumentos de tipo keyword, por tanto será un diccionario. Para argumentos posicionales se usa `*args` por convención. No es incorrecto en cuanto al lenguaje, pero si en cuanto a convenciones de estilo, puede confundir.

---

```
def mayusculas_y_minusculas (*args):  
    for word in args:
        if len(word) % 2 == 0:
            print(word.upper())
        else:
            print(word.lower())

mayusculas_y_minusculas ("hola", "ADIÓS")
```

> ```
> HOLA
> adiós
> ```

Usas `letter` como nombre de variable, lo cual contradice un poco lo que expresas en la pegunta y el propio código que intentas aplicar, si quieres que lo que se evalúe como par o impar sea la posición del carácter en la palabra, entonces no debes usar len sino aplicar el módulo sobre el índice:

```
def mayusculas_y_minusculas (*args):  
    for word in args:
        for i, letter in enumerate(word):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                print(letter.upper(), end="")
            else:
                print(letter.lower(), end="")
        print()

mayusculas_y_minusculas ("hola", "ADIÓS")
```

> ```
> HoLa
> AdIóS
> ```

Comment: Me refería a que la primera palabra sea minúscula, la segunda mayúsculas y así...

Comment: Vale, en tal caso ¿a la función como la llamarías: `mayusculas_y_minusculas("hola", "adiós")` o `mayusculas_y_minusculas("hola adiós")`?, es decir, un número indeterminado de palabras sueltas o una sola cadena con varias palabras, porque son cosa muy distintas.

Comment: Perdón, perdón, perdón! Dije palabra y es cada letra!

Comment: Pero entonces es mi segundo ejemplo ¿o no? Si no sería recomendable que agregaras la salida esperada para por ejemplo `mayusculas_y_minusculas ("hola", "comunidad", "de", "stackoverflow")` para que no andemos perdidos...XD